# Use `SharedPreferences` to store authentication token

Tags: android

I use token based authenticated mechanism on my server. When user logins through Android app the server returns token which needs to be sent with each subsequent request. I need to store that value on the devices. Since token is a simple string, I thought I'd use `SharedPreferences` to hold that value. When application starts inside `MyApplication extends Application` I query `SharedPreferences` for this token and hold it inside `MyApplication` as a global state so that every activity could access it when it sends request to the server.

Is this approach viable? If not, what critical drawbacks does it have? And if it's a bad idea, what's the alternative approach?

PS. This is not a subjective question - I'm not asking for `the best` approach, I'm validating my assumptions.

Comment: Have you considered using the android AccountManager? with setAuthToken and getAuthToken?

Comment: I haven't, thanks for the hint. At first glance it seems more difficult to implement though than keeping the token through `SharedPreferences`. But I might consider it for the future

Comment: yeah it definitely is a headache. Just is the "proper" approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly safe. The users wont have access to the `SharedPreferences` unless they have rooted their devices. If you're concerned about security that much, you could encrypt the token before storing it inside `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 2):

it is a valid option, if you don't want to use a `database` or write the token on a file. No drawbacks that I can think of

Answer (score 1):

It has one fault if the device is rooted. The user can see the token from SharedPreferences from their device if the device is rooted. I suggest you to store the data to the database/SQLite using Sugar [here](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) for better approach to your server.